# Perform same case statement on list of columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, dynamic-sql

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Name    …   Column  A1  A2  B1  B2  C1  …
Name1   …   value1  5   3   1   5   2   …
Name2   …   value2  4   4   2   3   4   …
Name3   …   value3  3   5   5   5   1   …
```

On the left there are some columns that store strings. On the right there are a bunch of columns that store values from 1-5.

I need to write a query that returns:

```
Name    A1  A2  B1  B2  C1  …
Name1   100 50  0   100 25  …
Name2   75  75  25  50  75  …
Name3   50  100 100 100 0   …
```

I need to select the Name column, then all of the columns on the right. I need to transform the 1-5 values to 0-100 values that represent scores (5 maps to 100, 4 maps to 75, and so on).

If there are only a few "score" columns, I can do this easily with a case statement. For example, when A1 is the only score column:

```
SELECT Name
    ,CASE when A1 = 5 then 100
    when A1 = 4 then 75
    when A1 = 3 then 50
    when A1 = 2 then 25
    when A1 = 1 then 0
    else null
    END as score
```

But it's not practical to do that if I have a hundred score columns.

I'd like to be able to pass in a string of `'A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,...'` and have my query perform the above case statement on each of the column names in the string. Is there any way to do that? Or is there a better approach?

I've looked into while loops, functions, stored procedures, and dynamic SQL a bit, but I've never used any of those and didn't find anything I could directly apply.

Comment: The problem you are running into is because you have a poor design of your table. You have violated 1NF with what is known as repeating groups. This is compounded by the fact that you don't have a real mapping from the option to a value via a lookup table. The best solution would be to normalize your data structure and then retrieving this information would be simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `SELECT Name, 25*(A1-1) AS A1, 25*(A2-1) AS A2 ...` I would think.

As for your second question, you could generate a large part of your query by running:

```
SELECT ', 25*(' + COLUMN_NAME + '-1) AS ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''''  AS 'SELECT Name'
FROM YourDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable'
AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Name'
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I might be overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

itsLex solution would be my first choice (+1), but if you'll need to generate non-linear scores, another option is **CHOOSE()**

```
Select Name
      ,[Column]
      ,A1  = choose(A1,0,25,50,75,100) 
      ,A2  = choose(A2,0,25,50,75,100) 
      ,B1  = choose(B1,0,25,50,75,100) 
      ,B2  = choose(B2,0,25,50,75,100) 
      ,C1  = choose(C1,0,25,50,75,100) 
 From YourTable
```

Returns

```
Name    Column  A1  A2  B1  B2  C1
Name1   value1  100 50  0   100 25
Name2   value2  75  75  25  50  75
Name3   value3  50  100 100 100 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to have your statement generated and executed all automatically:

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQLString = (SELECT ', 25*(' + COLUMN_NAME + '-1) AS ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''''   
FROM yourDatanase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable'
AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Name' 
FOR XML PATH (''));
DECLARE @SQLString2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQLString2 = 'SELECT Name' + @SQLString + ' FROM yourTable';
EXEC (@SQLString2)
```

Suppose you insist on having a restricting list of columns you want to see:

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQLString = (SELECT ', 25*(' + COLUMN_NAME + '-1) AS ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''''   
FROM yourDatanase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable'
AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2') 
FOR XML PATH (''));
DECLARE @SQLString2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQLString2 = 'SELECT Name' + @SQLString + ' FROM yourTable';
EXEC (@SQLString2)
```

Never did this in SQL Server before, but it can come in handy to execute a generated query this way.